# using xlwt, insert sql select query result to a cell in xls

Tags: python

I am trying to write the result of a sql select query to a xls file.
Below is the code:

```
RowNum = 8
sql = """select * from #table"""
cursor = self.db_conn.cursor()
cursor.execute(sql)
rb = open_workbook(settings.FILE_NAME,formatting_info=True)
wb = copy(rb)

sheet1 = wb.get_sheet('Sheet 1')

for row in cursor.fetchall():
    sheet1.write(RowNum, 0, row) # row, column, value
    RowNum = RowNum + 1

wb.save(settings.FILE_NAME_New)
```

But I get the following error:

```
sheet1.write(RowNum, 0, row) # row, column, value
  File "python-3.4.3\lib\xlwt\Worksheet.py", line 1088, in write
    self.row(r).write(c, label, style)
  File "python-3.4.3\lib\xlwt\Row.py", line 254, in write
    raise Exception("Unexpected data type %r" % type(label))
Exception: Unexpected data type <class 'pyodbc.Row'>
```

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 1):

`row` is not a literal value, it is a `pyodbc.Row`. Depending on the value of which column of the row you want, use this:

```
column_number = 0
sheet1.write(RowNum, 0, row[column_number]) # row, column, value
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to mention the column_number, You are trying to write the pyodbc object on the file rather than a particular column.

```
RowNum = 8
sql = """select * from #table"""
cursor = self.db_conn.cursor()
cursor.execute(sql)
rb = open_workbook(settings.FILE_NAME,formatting_info=True)
wb = copy(rb)

sheet1 = wb.get_sheet('Sheet 1')
column_no = 0
for row in cursor.fetchall():
    sheet1.write(RowNum, 0, row[column_no]) # change this line
    RowNum = RowNum + 1

wb.save(settings.FILE_NAME_New)
```